# Getting an input from QLineEdit and sending it to another python file for calculation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-module, qlineedit

I am writing a GUI. My GUI receives an integer input through `QLineEdit` and the input should be transferred to another python script where it performs calculations. The `GUI.py` file calls the python file `Calculation.py` through `subprocess.call`. When I try to send arguments to `Calculation.py`, it throws an error :

```
error "TypeError: Unsupported operand type for /: 'str' and 'int'".
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: QLineEdit returns a string, you can convert it to floating or integer. Or better use QSpinBox.

Comment: I tried QSpinBox. the code is:     
self.B_value = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)   
checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox('Test', self)    
checkBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda:self.run4('Calculation.py',self.B_value.text())) def run4(self, path, B_value):
B_value = int(self.B_value.text())
print(type(B_value))
print(B_value)
subprocess.call(['python3', path, 'Calculation.py', B_value], shell=True)    
Second file "Calculation.py": 
Value=sys.argv[0]
x=0xD0
y=0x00
a = Value
print(a)
b = int(((a*255)/100)+1)
c = b>>4
B_d = c+x
print(B_d). 

error:unsupported operand type(s) for /:'str' and 'int'

Comment: never put code in the comments, nobody understands it or nobody wanted to understand it. edit your question and add it there, take time and read [ask]

Comment: Hi eyllansec, problem fixed. thanks for your help.